# Exam grades and bell curve

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the mathematical explanation for the tendency of exam grades to conform to a bell curve?
Initially, I was thinking it should be explained via the central limit theorem, but it's not clear to me why it should apply.

Comment: You could consider the questions on the exam as IID trials, then the total exam grade is given by the sum of these trials, and the CLT applies.

Comment: In my experience raw math exam grades do not have an even close to normal distribution.

Comment: @AndréNicolas interesting. So why is there an association between the bell curve and grades?
Jordan: Yes, but why is the IID assumption reasonable?

Comment: Some people (but not so much in math) do post-manipulation of grades so that the histogram will have the "bell" shape. There is no good justification.

Comment: I was always confused by some professors obsession with "curving" a test to "correct" for a test that was too easy or hard. If I were a professor, I would want ALL of my students to get a 100% (clearly not bell shaped) and its my job as a professor to make sure the questions are properly calibrated...not some mechanical curving scheme.

Answer (score 0):

In the interests of engaging constructively with this question, here is one possible way a test could plausibly be bell-shaped:

Lets say there are $N$ students in the class. We can represent their level of preparedness for the exam by a "correct answer" probability, $p_i$, which we can interpret as the fraction of questions they would get correct if they repeatedly took practice tests without seeing the answers.

If there are $M$ questions on the test, then each student's score $S_i$ will be a binomial random variable $S_i \sim Bin(M,p_i)$.

If the level of preparedness of the students cluster around a certain value, and that value is not close to zero or one, then you'll get a bell-shaped curve (with some skew). Technically, this distribution will something like a [Beta-Binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution), where the beta distribution describes the distribution of preparedness levels of the students. Ideally, you'd like to see this distribution skewed to have more $p_i$ closer to $1$, indicating you've prepared them well...but there will be potentially long tail towards zero, which will be the poorly prepared students (partiers, never-come-to-classers, out of my depthers).

Of course, this really only applies to very large classes (those massive intro courses with 400+ students). Small classes will have a general multinomial distribution.